# How to drop rows that contains specific value three or more times in dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe

In dataframe of pandas, Python3

How can I drop rows that contains a particular value three or more times.

For example,

input :

```
Date    A   B   C   D   E   F   G   H

2018-11-16  82873   -420    -18974  0   233064  105 4671

2018-11-17  -67566  0   17348   -7281   0   -358    0

2018-11-18  117400  -6030   0   -7734   761842  0   935

2018-11-21  -101588 0   192 0   135460  7251    0

2018-11-22  0   63148   0   2032    0   3902    1347
```

expected output:

```
Date    A   B   C   D   E   F   G   H

2018-11-16  82873   -420    -18974  0   233064  105 4671

2018-11-18  117400  -6030   0   -7734   761842  0   935
```

Comment: What you have tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `pandas.DataFrame.eq` with `sum` and `ge`:

```
df[~df.eq(0).sum(1).ge(3)]
```

Output:

```
         Date       A     B      C     D       E    F     G   H
0  2018-11-16   82873  -420 -18974     0  233064  105  4671 NaN
2  2018-11-18  117400 -6030      0 -7734  761842    0   935 NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
import pandas as pd
data = """2018-11-16  82873   -420    -18974  0   233064  105 4671
2018-11-17  -67566  0   17348   -7281   0   -358    0
2018-11-18  117400  -6030   0   -7734   761842  0   935
2018-11-21  -101588 0   192 0   135460  7251    0
2018-11-22  0   63148   0   2032    0   3902    1347""".split('\n')
data = [r.split() for r in data]
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(data)
from collections import defaultdict
def find(x):
  cnt = defaultdict(int)
  for i in x:
    cnt[i] += 1
  for v in cnt.values():
    if v >= 3:
      return False
  return True
cols = df.apply(find,axis=1)  
df[cols]
```

Output (you can add the columns yourself, I'm just doing a quick example)

```
0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7
0   2018-11-16  82873   -420    -18974  0   233064  105 4671
2   2018-11-18  117400  -6030   0   -7734   761842  0   935
```